# SP 2013 Workflow Needs to Calculate Due Date using Payment Terms and Date Received

Tags: workflow, 2013

I have a due date in one list that needs to be populated by a workflow to calculate the date received plus the payment terms.  So, if the date received is 4/3/2013 and the terms are 30 then the resulting due date needs to be 5/2/2013.  How do I setup this calculation in a workflow using Sharepoint Designer 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "**Add Time to Date**" action in SPD 2013

See this for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164026.aspx

> Adds a specific time in minutes, hours, days, or months to a date
>   (Year is not supported), and stores the output value as a variable.
>   The date can be a current data, specific date, or a lookup. The
>   ‘Current Date’ value returns UTC midnight