# SharePoint Designer 2013 make a contract due date workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a contracts library.

In that library I want to track the contracts and send notifications to Contract owners 30 days before the Due date as a reminder that they need to take action.

What would I need to do in order to trigger the workflow to start and what would I need to do for the workflow to calculate the date correct?

Flow is not an option.
Coding in c# or java is not an option.
Document retention Policy is not an option.

Only OOTB SharePoint Designer solutions please.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options to start a workflow:

- on item added
- on item changed

Assuming that the DueDate is entered when the Contract is created, you should set your workflow to start on item added. 

Next step will be to calculate the date for sending email. Create a new variable and set it to DueDate-30 days. Have a look at these posts:

- [SP 2013 Workflow Needs to Calculate Due Date using Payment Terms and Date Received](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64784/sp-2013-workflow-needs-to-calculate-due-date-using-payment-terms-and-date-receiv)
- [add days to date in sharepoint designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144232/add-days-to-date-in-sharepoint-designer)

Then Wait/Pause until the DueDate-30.
Lastly, use Send an Email Step and GO TO End of Workflow Step.

*If you have millions of items starting the workflows, this solution will not work. If it is 20-100 - it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I developed few solutions having a similar requirement. Best method I found was the following:

A create/modify workflow on contracts which sets a Reminder Date field for Due Date - 30 days

Then a site workflow doing the following:

```
Stage 1
- ID = Lookup Contracts where Reminder Date is Today (this only returns the first match)
- If match found, send notification, set Reminder Date to something else (such as Reminder Date + 7) and goto Stage 1 (look for next match)
- Wait 1 day (if no match found)
- Go to stage 1 (start scanning the list again)
```